# How can I convert this query into inner join

Tags: sql

```
SELECT * FROM fihrist,fihristAyet,ayetler,sureler WHERE
fihrist.fihrist_id=fihristAyet.fihristAyet_fihrist_id AND
fihristAyet.fihristAyet_ayet=ayetler.ayet_no AND
fihristAyet.fihristAyet_sure_id=ayetler.sure_id AND
fihristAyet.fihristAyet_sure_id=sureler.sure_id AND
fihristAyet.fihristAyet_fihrist_id=564
```

How can I do with inner join. I tried this code, but it didn't.

```
SELECT * FROM fihrist
INNER JOIN fihristayet ON fihrist.fihrist_id=fihristayet.fihristAyet_id
INNER JOIN ayetler ON fihristayet.fihristAyet_ayet=ayetler.ayet_no AND fihristayet.fihristAyet_sure_id=ayetler.sure_id
INNER JOIN sureler ON fihristayet.fihristAyet_sure_id=sureler.sure_id
WHERE fihristayet.fihristAyet_fihrist_id=564
```

Comment: Can you update your question with a sample dataset of all the tables, expected output of the query and with the error description?

Comment: Please go through basics of joins.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/performance/joins?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: no data appearing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you could do this;

```
SELECT * 
FROM fihrist f
 INNER JOIN fihristAyet fa
    ON f.fihrist_id=fa.fihristAyet_fihrist_id
 INNER JOIN ayetler ay
    ON fa.fihristAyet_ayet=ay.ayet_no
 INNER JOIN sureler s 
    ON fa.fihristAyet_sure_id = s.sure_id AND fa.fihristAyet_sure_id = ay.sure_id
WHERE fa.fihristAyet_fihrist_id=564
```